# Assigning portions of a line to a variable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following values in a txt file

```
blabla:loremispum:78467887844
loremispum:blabla:74365323
soandso:loremispum:67545667
```

I want to print out the values in a format like

```
username:blabla
Realname:loremispum
id #:78467887844

username:loremispum
Realname:blabla
id #:74365323

username:soandso
Realname:loremispum
id #:67545667
```

How would I go about this in python?

Comment: Look up ```string.split()```

Comment: More generally, look at the `csv` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have a text file called `file.txt` with the following contents:

```
blabla:loremispum:78467887844
loremispum:blabla:74365323
soandso:loremispum:67545667
```

You could read the file line by line and utilize [str.**split**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        username, realname, identifier = line.split(':')
        print(f'username:{username}')
        print(f'Realname:{realname}')
        print(f'id #:{identifier}')
```

**Output:**

```
username:blabla
Realname:loremispum
id #:78467887844

username:loremispum
Realname:blabla
id #:74365323

username:soandso
Realname:loremispum
id #:67545667
```

Try it out [**here**](https://repl.it/repls/LovelyYoungParallelport#main.py).